# Is there a closed form for the zeroes of these $\cos$-like and $\sin$-like functions?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, roots

There is a nice $\exp$-like function, which can be defined on $\mathbb{R}$ by its Taylor series or by an integral:

$$p(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{(k+1)^{k+1}}=\int_0^1 u^{-u x}du$$

I had a thought to define $\cos$-like and $\sin$-like functions the same way they are defined for the exponent:

> $$pc(x)=\frac{1}{2}(p(ix)+p(-ix))=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k x^{2k}}{(2k+1)^{2k+1}}=\int_0^1 \cos (x ~u \ln u)du$$

[image]

> $$ps(x)=\frac{1}{2i}(p(ix)-p(-ix))=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k x^{2k+1}}{(2k+2)^{2k+2}}=-\int_0^1 \sin (x~ u \ln u)du$$

[image]

I'm not sure how to use either of these definitions to find the zeroes (or the maxima/minima, etc) of $pc(x)$ and $ps(x)$.

> I guess like for Bessel functions there might be no closed form expressions for these zeroes. But how to find them numerically in an effective way, without trial and error and computing either the series or the integral several times?

Comment: The smallest value of $|u \ln(u) |$ in the interval $[0,1]$ is 1/e. Thinking very roughly, if we imagine $\int_0^1 \sin(x u \ln(u))du$ as a sum of sine waves with different periods, then the shortest period will be $2\pi e$. This could give us a estimate of the spacing between even roots; using the estimate that the $n$'th even root is at $2\pi e n $ I calculate that the first three even roots are at ${17.1, 34.2,51.2}$, which is somewhat consistent with the graph. If we get a good enough estimate of the spacing we can generate very good guesses for Newton's method to start with.

Comment: Using the method of stationary phase I get that $$\operatorname{pc}(x) \approx \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{e x}} \left( \sin \frac{x}{e} + \cos \frac{x}{e} \right) \quad \text{as } x \to \pm \infty,$$ so we can expect that the large zeros of $\operatorname{pc}(x)$ are $x \approx e(\pi n - \pi/4)$, $n \in \mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note** this isn't intended to be a complete answer, but rather a record of the progress I've made so far. Hopefully others can build on this and improve the estimation method.

---

To efficiently calculate the roots of these functions numerically Newton's method would seem advisable. However this method requires an estimate of the location of these roots to use as a seed value. If our estimate is not sufficiently close to our desired root it will converge to some other zero fo the function.

Informally integrals are a sort of continuous summation. Using this as a heuristic I decided to think of the integral $-\int_0^1 \sin(x u\ln(u))du$ as a superposition of sine waves, each with a frequency $u\ln(u)$. Of these frequencies there is a maximum frequency of $1/e$. From this I concluded that consecutive even roots, which approximately correspond to 1 period of a sinusoid, shouldn't be closer than $2\pi e$. Since the first even root occurs at $x=0$ I was able to estimate that the first three even roots should occur near $\lbrace 17.1,34.2,51.2 \rbrace$.

Using this method I got the following results for the first 6 even roots. In each case, except for the last one, I stopped the iterations when ps(r) was on the order of $10^{-15}$.

I haven't yet thoroughly tested the method for higher roots, which is a point of possible failure. The following roots are for $ps(x)$ in particular.

- r_2 :

Guess=17.07946844

Final Result=18.70552649220349

Number of Iterations = 4

- r_4 :

Guess=34.15893689

Final Result=35.93348821178866

Number of Iterations = 4

- r_6 :

  Guess=51.23840533

  Final Result=53.08048121487314

  Number of Iterations = 4
- r_8 :

Guess=68.31787378

Final Result=70.20033529768552

Number of Iterations = 4

- r_10 :

Guess=85.39734222

Final Result=87.3073325217411

Number of Iterations=4

- r_12 :

Guess=102.4768107

Final Result=104.407075063793409825332380293

( $ps(r)\approx 10^{-18}$ using 200 terms in the series)

Number of Iterations=4

---

I discovered an interesting result. $u\ln(u)$ has an extreme value at $u=1/e$. Near this point the integral will get its most significant contribution if $|\sin(x/e)|=1$; this occurs when $x=\pi e/2 + n\pi/2$. For those fixed values of $x$ the integrand will be very flat and boxy near the critical point, but highly oscillatory elsewhere in the interval.

The taylor series of the integrand centered at $u=1/e$ is,

$$-(-1)^n+\frac{1}{32}(-1)^n\pi^2e^4(1+2n)^2(u-1/e)^4,$$

To estimate the integral for large odd $n$ we can do a sort of saddle point approximation and treat the integrand as being,

$$ f(u)=\exp(-\frac{1}{32}\pi^2e^4(1+2n)^2(u-1/e)^4) + \text{(highly oscillatory terms)}$$

Clearly a change of variables could be performed in the integral to pull out the $n$-dependence; this would result in a prefactor on the order of $1/\sqrt{n}$. This explains why the peaks seem to roughly fall as $1/\sqrt{x}$.

I will do some numerical experiments later to see how well this can be used to predict the locations of the extrema.

Comment: Curious. ISC finds nothing for the first two roots, I don't think it will be any different for the other roots. It's likely there is no closed form. But your method seems to be working well. Maybe using the series will be better though?

Comment: Thats interesting about the ISC, I hadn't thought to use that calculator. One of my doubts about using the series is that it alternates; such series generally gobble up your numerical precision. Regardless I'll play around with the computations over the next couple of days and see what improvements I can get.

Comment: Ok I remembered that I have Maple on this machine, which has arbitrary precision arithmetic and I got a significant improvement on r_12 using the power series.

Comment: Thank you for this great answer! I will  wait some time before accepting it, it's possible that someone else becomes interested in this problem